# SilverStripe Custom Email Form - jQuery.ajax not passing variables to server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, silverstripe

I'm trying to build out a custom email form for a SilverStripe site that's a mix of jQuery, HTML, PHP, and SilverStripe API, and I've been stuck on trying to get the form fields over to the server side. And please, please NO suggestions for form plugins--the form is setup as it is and I am not going to go back and spend hours redoing it.

Here is the function that is getting and supposedly sending the form data to the server:

```
function ajax_script() {
  var form_data = {
    firstname: SchFirstName.val(),
    lastname: SchLastName.val(),
    useremail: SchEmail.val(),
    birthday: SchBirthday.val(),
    phone: SchPhone.val(),
    servicereq: SchService.val(),
    location: SchLocation.val(),
    doctor: SchDoctor.val(),
    calltime: SchTime.val()
  };
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/home/ScheduleAppointment",
    data: form_data,
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
}
```

And here is the ScheduleAppointment function in the Page.php controller:

```
public function ScheduleAppointment() {
     $fname = $this->getRequest()->param('firstname');
     $lname = $this->getRequest()->param('lastname');
     $birthday= $this->getRequest()->param('birthday');
     $useremail= $this->getRequest()->param('useremail');
     $phone = $this->getRequest()->param('phone');
     $servicereq = $this->getRequest()->param('servicereq');
     $location = $this->getRequest()->param('location');
     $doctor = $this->getRequest()->param('doctor');
     $calltime = $this->getRequest()->param('calltime');

     $from = '[hidden]';
     $to = '[hidden]';
     $subject = 'Appointment Request Submission';

     $body = "First Name: ".$fname."\r\n"."Last Name: ".$lname."\r\n"."Date of Birth: ".$birthday."\r\n"."Phone Number: ".$phone."\r\n"."Email: ".$useremail."\r\n"."Best Time to Call: ".$calltime."\r\n"."Location/Hospital: ".$location."\r\n"."Physician: ".$doctor."\r\n"."Service Requested: ".$servicereq."\r\n" ";

     $email = new Email($from, $to, $subject, $body);
     $email->replyTo($useremail);

     $email->send();
}
```

I have tried debugging the form, and I can see that the variables are all `null` (`$fname`, `$lname`, `$birthday`, etc), so something isn't right. Either the `jQuery.ajax` function is flawed or the `this->getRequest()->param()` setup is correct.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix the issue, I would be very grateful. I've been trying to solve the problem for hours and I am pretty much stumped right now.

Comment: Can you console log the data just before posting?

Comment: @BasvanStein I can get that much going. In the debugger in PHP Storm, I see that the $_POST variable has all the form field data from the ajax function but the variables inside the ScheduleAppointment form are all null regardless. I am guessing something is wrong with how the getRequest() code is setup, and it's not reading the data.

Comment: `$this->getRequest()->postVar('firstname');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Steve noted in the comment:

```
$this->request->param('foo');
```

is wrong. It's for getting stuff out of URL parameters, as $Action, $ID or whatever you define in your routes or `$url_handlers` ([see docs](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SS_HTTPRequest.html#_param))

To get POST vars, you need to call:

```
$this->request->postVar('foo');
```

To get both, POST or GET vars you can call:

```
$this->request->requestVar('foo');
```

[See docs](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SS_HTTPRequest.html#_requestVar)

Comment: I wasn't even thinking of that...I was thinking of "get" in a different way. I totally overlooked the POST aspect of the form....Dumb mistake but at least now I know. It seems to have solved the issue as I can now send out emails for testing. Thanks!